# Gauss-Bonnet theorem proof considering membrane Force and hydrostatic fluid Pressure equilibrium

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, geometric-interpretation

*Is it possible to prove Gauss-Bonnet Theorem by using physics (Mechanics of materials) models?*

For example in mechanics  could one consider static equilibrium by action of hydrostatic pressure normal to  a patch, tension in the curved patch boundary line or using strain energy, or by considering tension forces and/or moments in all three directions?

Surface Tension property $N$ or force per unit arc length of a closed boundary (or membrane energy in creating a new unit area), $N$ can balance pressure on a spherical soap-film as $ p = 2 N \kappa_n , $ where $\kappa_n$ is normal curvature of the bubble or by mean curvature  $  2 H = p /N $ for a doubly curved patch.

EDIT1:

My attempt ... Gauss Bonnet theorem for a singly connected patch. Proposing here an elementary physics model :

$$ \int K dA  + \int k_g ds = 2 \pi\tag{1} $$

Defining elemental force $dF$ linking the above solid and tangential membrane " rotations" as applicable for pressure and surface tension by means of their force component  $ dF$:

$$ dF = p \,dA  \cos \phi  = N \,ds \sin \phi ;\ \tag{2}$$

we have $$    \int  \left( \frac{K}{p \cos \phi} +  \frac{k_g}{ N\sin \phi } \right) dF = 2 \pi\tag{3}$$

as a topological constant.. However getting a full physical sense is elusive, at time of posting but was soon changed  as following.

EDIT2:

Answering own question at least partially ..

We can derive Gauss Bonnet by considering mechanical Force Equilibrium of a spherical segment of the soap bubble in the following manner taken after equilibrium considerations of spherical or cylindrical pressure vessels... the attempt appears to me this way now, but may still need revision :

[image: Gauss Bonnet Thm static EQUILIBRIUM proof]

Considering static force and pressure equilibria, net force in horizontal direction is zero.

$$ 2 \pi R \cdot  p  \Delta z + N\cdot 2 \pi r  = 0 $$

$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi R \cdot  p  \Delta z} +\frac{1}{ N\cdot 2 \pi r } = 0  \tag{4}$$

Divide numerator and denominator of each term by $R$ and let

$$ 1/R^2 = K ;\, \Delta z/R = \cos \phi ;\,  r/R = \sin \phi \,; 1/R = k_g\, ;\tag{5} $$

$$ \frac{ 1/R^2}{2 \pi p (\Delta z/R) } + \frac {1/R}{2 \pi N ( r/R) } \tag{6}$$

$$ \frac{ K } { 2 \pi p\cos \phi} + \frac { k_g}{ 2 \pi N \sin \phi} = 0  \tag {7} $$

which relation when multiplied by $dF$ and integrated we get the same form of of Gauss Bonnet theorem Equn (3) with $2 \pi$ now appearing as an integration constant which can be  identified as a topological constant.

EDIT 3:

Essentially it is seen that physical model geometrization is made  possible by looking at *area as reciprocal of pressure* $p$ and boundary *length as reciprocal of surface tension* $T.$

The insight applied so far is that in a soap film application of pressure increases its area and boundary line dilations occur by linear (uni-axial) tension. The correct model should include ***all*** doubly curved surfaces, not spherical the surfaces only .

Comment: Mean curvature, not Gaussian curvature, I believe.

Comment: H is  for soap film,  and how should it be for  GB thm with K?

Comment: It's still mean curvature, but in the spherical case, it's the same thing up to a factor of $2$. How do you hope to get Gaussian curvature into this picture?

Comment: I expect.the equilibrium models to be quite different with K and H,e.g., $\int K dA $ may come in the former.

Comment: Where it may come up: the discrete case, in structural analysis where basically you are counting degrees of freedom (vertices, edges, faces - is a system rigid or not), and in the continuous case, in the topological questions (the hairy ball theorem comes up in fluid dynamics on a sphere, in liquid crystals,...), and more directly, in membrane physics (there is also a gaussian curvature term, which is then of course integrated out by GBT). It comes up in write-twist-link identities in elasticity of closed rods. In any case, it's usually used the other way around.

Comment: Can you please give a full answer as applicable to a membrane? What forces/properties  are considered, and how we end up in a pure geometry GB theorem result.

Comment: A useful link: http://phys.libretexts.org/LibreTexts/University_of_California_Davis/UCD%3A_Biophysics_241/Membrane_Curvature

The problem is, that in physics, formulas are usually built by sticking together allowed terms with unknown constants, and in any case, this is where you *use* the GBT to show that term is for a closed membrane independent from shape, not the other way around.

Comment: What differential equations with scalar  *Membrane Bend Elasticity* ( dimn 1/L^3) describe length and curvature changes?

Comment: It seems you have derived a relationship between pressure $p$ and surface tension $N$ for a sphere in equilibrium. I don't see how this proves the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

Comment: It does not prove GBT fully as yet. What I am trying is an approach for proof /development, so can be only partially correct as of now. I have at present no claim to its completeness and so correctness.Trying to fill in gaps about double curvature, geometry etc.. My motivation was to somehow start attempting  it due to an intuition about it fwiw, especially that I found so far no such approach in literature available..that too for such an important topic !. I feel reasonably certain, GBT is in other words a statement of static equilibrium.

Comment: 18th century mathematicians made natural/physical models with mathematical (geometrical) definition, Gauss, in modelling Earth's curvature for land survey, electrostatics etc. and Euler in Column instability, Variational calculus Optics etc...Wondered why Gauss did not make such an attempt himself, or the other mathematicians...

Comment: I had put in a bounty for this and there were no takers.